# scrapy pipelines cant insert data into sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

It works fine when creating table but doesn't insert any data at all. Does anyone know what might be the issues?

This is my pipeline

```
import sqlite3

class HelloPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):#
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite")
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute("create table if not exists test(test1 text, test2 text, test3 text,test4 text, test5 text, test6 text, test7 text);")        
        #pass

    def close_spider(self, spider):#
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()
        #pass

    def process_item(self, item, spider):#

        col = ",".join(item.keys())       
        placeholders = ",".join(len(item) * "?")
        sql = "insert into test({}) values({})"#
        self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), item.values())

        return item
```

This is items

```
import scrapy


class HelloItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    test1 = scrapy.Field()
    ...
    test7 = scrapy.Field()
```

This is the main programme

```
class crawler(scrapy.Spider):

...

    def parse (self, response):
        for data_house in jsondata["data"]["data"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(house_detail_domain.format(data_house["post_id"]), self.parse_house_detail)


    def parse_house_detail (self, response):
    ...    

    testitem = HelloItem()

    testitem["test1"] = house_detail.select(".houseInfoTitle")        
    ...
    testitem["test7"] = house_detail.select(".facility")[0].text
    return testitem
```

tell me if there is any info missing

Comment: Scrapy spiders use pipelines, typically. Not the other way around. without knowing how the spider calls the pipeline, I don't know how to answer

Comment: Thank ur reminding, I have updated the code. And the setting part is like 
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'hello.pipelines.HelloPipeline': 1000,
}

Comment: Could also provide us with the scrapy logs?

Comment: wow u guys r pro, the logs were too long for me to figure out but it truly shows the problem!

Answer (score 0):

cool, the logs do show the problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\meow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\meow\Desktop\hello\hello\pipelines.py", line 27, in process_item
    self.cur.execute(sql.format(col, placeholders), item.values())
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
2018-02-23 19:13:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

2018-02-23 19:13:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```